# Debian Server - stable + backports or sid?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, patch-management

I have Debian Lenny, since it's stable most of the packages are rather outdated, example being SQLAlchemy 0.4, whereas the current version is 0.5.x. I'm wondering if I should go with setting up backports ( if so how should I specifically set them up so that just individual packages I choose are upgraded ), or make it `sid` so I can grab some more up to date packages.

Comment: What's your server being used for? How much do you value stability? I think this is really only a question you can answer for yourself.

Comment: Another option may be to use ubuntu server.  It is very similar to Debian and tends to be updated a lot more frequently.

Comment: Ubuntu? Yeah if he wants RC and beta software on his server.

Comment: It seems like a good compromise would be to use testing instead of unstable.  Why is that not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're capable of building, backporting, and maintaining your own package tree, then go with stable, because I can almost guarantee that some of what you want won't be backported already.  Otherwise, go with sid and only update when you need to (and keep a careful eye on updates for security advisories).